# Slow performance when deleting huge amount of rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, activerecord

### The problem

I'm trying to parse huge CSV file (27mb) and delete big amount of rows, but running in performance issues.

### Specifications

- rails version 4.2.0, Posgtres as db client
- **videos** table has **300000** rows
- **categories_videos** pivot table has **885000** rows
- To load the external csv file takes **29097ms**
- External CSV file has **3117000** lines (1 deleted video id per line)

### The task

I have large CSV file **27MB** with the IDs of videos which were deleted and I have to go through this file and check if there are any videos in my database that would have matching ID and if they have delete them from my db.

**1) roughly 126724ms (per chunk)**

```
file_location = 'http://my_external_source/file.csv';
open(file_location, 'r:utf-8') do |f| 

    data = SmarterCSV.process(f, { :headers_in_file => false, :user_provided_headers => ["id"], :chunk_size => 1000 }) do |chunk|
        chunk = chunk.map{ |row| row[:id] }
        Video.delete_all(:id => chunk)
        VideoCategoryRelation.delete_all(:video_video_id => chunk)
    end

end
```

**2) roughly 90000ms (per chunk)**

```
file_location = 'http://my_external_source/file.csv';
open(file_location, 'r:utf-8') do |f| 

    data = SmarterCSV.process(f, { :headers_in_file => false, :user_provided_headers => ["id"], :chunk_size => 1000 }) do |chunk|
        chunk = chunk.map{ |row| row[:id] }
        Video.where(:video_id => chunk).destroy_all
    end

end
```

Is there any efficient way how to go through this that would note take hours?

Comment: First, I would probably use Sidekiq or something similar, so you can run this task in the background in case you are doing this on a production server. Next you should find a way to reduce the number of queries to the database. You could collect the ids in chunks and then every 30 lines or so make one request with the collected ids.

Comment: Oh, and probably try to use plain sql to delete them, as the destroy_all is loading the objects first. If there are no hooks on before or after destroy, I would definitely prefer that over the destroy.

Comment: but doesn't delete_all runs without any hooks and yet it's still so slow?
I have been looking in resque and sidekiq and I will use it, but still that I feel that it takes really long for such a "trivial" task.

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the `open` and pass the filename directly to SmarterCSV?

Comment: Reading the csv file is not the major performance problem, removing the data from DB is.

Comment: I agree that a straight `DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN ()` will do the trick. At least with that instruction you hand over the task to the database server, which is capable of handling the load. 2 questions: (1) why isn't the  standard cvs module a good fit for handling the file? (2) why do you keep the file open throughout the operation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Ruby or the database you are using, but it looks like there are a lot of separate delete calls to the database.

Here's what I would try to speed things up:

First, make sure you have an index on id in both tables.

In each table, create a field (boolean or small int) to mark a record for deletion. In your loop, instead of deleting, just set the deletion field to true (this should be fast if you have an index on id). And only at the end call delete once on each table (delete from table where the deletemarker is true).

Comment: this seams like very creative way how to go about my problem and I'm going to try it. Thank you.